# Loop that inputs characters in an array of structures does not work properly

Tags: c, arrays, loops, structure

The dictionary program should read the word(s) that the user inputs as either the "word" or "definition." The only problem is that for the first instance of the loop, the readLine function does not seem to be called, and this only happens when the word has to be stored in dictionary[0].word. It skips letting the user input the word for Entry #1.

How can I fix this?

```
// Enter words with their corresponding definitions

#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
{
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};



int main (void)
{
    int numberEntries;

    void inputEntry (struct entry dictionary[], int numberEntries);


    printf ("How many dictionary entries do you want to enter?.\n");
    scanf ("%i", &numberEntries);

    struct entry dictionary[numberEntries];

    inputEntry (dictionary, numberEntries);

    return 0;

}




void inputEntry (struct entry dictionary[], int numberEntries)
{
    void readLine (char buffer[]);
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < numberEntries; i++ ) {
        printf ("Entry #%i:\n", i + 1);
        printf ("Word: ");
        readLine (dictionary[i].word);

        printf ("Definition: ");
        readLine (dictionary[i].definition);

        printf ("\n");
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < numberEntries; i++ ) {
        printf ("\n%s", dictionary[i].word);
        printf ("\n%s", dictionary[i].definition);

    }

}

// Get a string and save it in an array

void readLine (char buffer[])
{
    char character;
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        character = getchar ();
        buffer[i] = character;
        i++;
    }
    while ( character != '\n' );

    buffer[i - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing use of `scanf` and `getchar` which is confusing things. The `scanf` will *only* read the integer that is typed, and then the next `getchar` will read the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress as a `\n`.

The easiest solution in your case would be to use `readLine` instead of `scanf`.

You may also consider the use of the standard function `fgets` instead of writing your own `readLine`. `fgets` is better because your function does not do bounds checking on the `buffer` parameter, leading to buffer overruns if you type too many characters on one line.

Comment: Were you able to run the program?

Comment: No, I'm not in a position when I can run your code right now. However, this is a common question and the reason for the problem was clear.

Comment: Although the program can be improved, I think the main problem has to do with saving in the array structure

Comment: Yes, and what I suggested will fix the problem you described. Did you try my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to strip the newline from the input buffer after using `scanf` is to use `getchar()`. This is recommended any time you need to read a second time from stdin:

```
char c;
...
scanf ("%i", &numberEntries);
do {
    c = getchar();
} while ( c != '\n');
```

You will then be able to enter the first word without problems:

```
./bin/dict
How many dictionary entries do you want to enter?.
3
Entry #1:
Word: dog
Definition: wags tail

Entry #2:
Word: cat
Definition: meows constantly

Entry #3:
Word: mouse
Definition: does little


dog
wags tail
cat
meows constantly
mouse
does little
```